# how to accomplish cross browser support when generating a css3 gradient via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

With a style tag or an external stylesheet file i can use the following to support various browsers:

```
#divID {
    background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

I have a page where the user can set the parameters for the gradient using sliders. If i try something like this the background css property would be overwritten with the next value that is being set by the css jquery setter:

```
$("#divID").css({background:"-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);"});
$("#divID").css({background:"-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1)));"});
...etc
```

Is there anyway i can accomplish the same with javascript or  jQuery as it is done with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method should work:

```
var bgWebKit = "-webkit-gradient(linear, " + ...;
var bgMoz    = "-moz-linear-gradient(" + ...;

$('#divID')
  .css({ background: bgWebKit })
  .css({ background: bgMoz });
```

As per [**this source**](http://css-tricks.com/8265-moving-highlight/)

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to have to dig around in the jquery code now, I want to know why that particular hack/workaround operates differently.

Comment: This changes the gradient in both browsers, i'm guessing the browser rejects unknown css parameters and when it encounters the ones he knows he accepts them? Anyway i think what i'm trying to accomplish isn't going to be possible. I'll try appending a style tag to the head or saving the background custom made crossbrowser css styles in a database and echo them with php in the style tag when the document is generated.